# What is wrong with my Floyd-Steinberg dithering implementation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, opencv

I have implemented the algorithm in python. When I run the code, it returns an image with strange patterns ( black spots ). I've reviewed it multiple times, but I cant find what the problem might be. I have also tried changing the direction in which the algorithm runs, but its no use.

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

def Dither(img):

    output = np.copy(img)

    for y in range(1,img.shape[0]-1):
        for x in range(1,img.shape[1]-1):
        
            pix = output[y][x]
            newpix = round(pix/255) * 255

            error = pix - newpix

            output[y][x] = newpix

            output[y    ][x + 1] += error * 7/16
            output[y + 1][x - 1] += error * 3/16
            output[y + 1][x    ] += error * 5/16
            output[y + 1][x + 1] += error * 1/16

    return(output)


img = np.array(cv.cvtColor(cv.imread("kitten.jpg"), cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))

plt.imshow(Dither(img), cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

The reason why the x and y variables are assigned in an unconventional order is that I have googled an implementation which had its variables flipped as well.

My result:
[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y9XU.jpg)

Expected result:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DXEL.png)

Comment: The elements of your image array are most likely uint8 - so you're getting wraparound problems when you add a negative error to a dark pixel, or a positive error to a light pixel.  In other words, your `Clamp()` was pointless, because values outside of the 0...255 range are simply not possible in a uint8 array. Simplest solution would be to copy your image data to an int16 array temporarily, so that you actually can have values less than 0 or greater than 255.

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your answer! It solved the problem. I have changed the array dtype to plain "int".